# Convert all small words (2-3 characters) to upper case with awk or sed

Tags: shell, text-processing, awk, sed, text

I need all 2-3 character words completely capitalized. 1 character and 4+ character words need to be remain untouched.

Input:

```
cat Example
Dog
I
Fish
su
Su adm
Amd Cat ignore
```

Expected output:

```
CAT Example
DOG
a
Fish
SU
SU ADM
ADM CAT ignore
```

Comment: Should `Let's` be converted to `LET's`, `LET'S` or not converted. How about `It's` or `i'm`? IOW, how do you define *word*?

Comment: There are no symbols in my file

Comment: Maybe the lowercase letter `a` is a better example than the uppercase letter `I`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Using GNU `sed`

```
$ sed -E 's/\<[[:alpha:]]{2,3}\>/\U&/g' input_file
DOG
I
Fish
SU
SU ADM
AMD CAT ignore
```

Comment: You have to be kidding me: GNU `sed` even handles unicode correctly!? I tried your solution with a file containing the string `sté` and it correctly converted it to `STÉ`!

Answer (score 7):

I would use perl instead:

```
$ perl -pe 's/\b\w{2,3}\b/uc($&)/eg' file
CAT Example
DOG
I
Fish
SU
SU ADM
AMD CAT ignore
```

If your file contains non-ASCII characters encoded in UTF-8 and your locale uses UTF-8 as the charmap, for example the string `sté` that should become `STÉ`, then use:

```
$ perl -C -pe 's/\b\w{2,3}\b/uc($&)/eg' file
CAT Example
DOG
I
Fish
SU
SU ADM
AMD CAT ignore
STÉ
```

Comment: Or `perl -pe's/\b\w{2,3}\b/\U$&/g'`, note that `\w` also matches on ASCII digits and underscores and only matches on ASCII letters. It would turn `Stéphane` to `STéphane` for instance.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas `\U` doesn't work for me, I always use `uc()` so I don't know why it fails, but it seems to be explecting a package: `Can't locate object method "U" via package "cat" (perhaps you forgot to load "cat"?) at -e line 1, <> line 1.` but using `$&` avoids the need for a capture group, so I added that. I also added a unicode aware version, thanks!

Comment: You must have kept the `e` flag.

Comment: Ooooh! Of course: so perl was looking for a function named `U`, got it. Thanks @StéphaneChazelas!

Answer (score 4):

This is a solution with awk:

```
awk '{ for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) { if (length($i) <= 3) { $i=toupper($i) } } }1' infile
```

Answer (score 2):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```
raku -pe 's:g/<?wb> \w**2..3 <?wb>/{$/.uc}/;'
```

OR

```
raku -pe 's:g/<|w> \w**2..3 <|w>/{$/.uc}/;'
```

OR

```
raku -pe 's:g/<< \w**2..3 >>/{$/.uc}/;'
```

The Raku code above is a fairly direct translation of @terdon's Perl code. Word boundaries are written either `<?wb>` or `<|w>` in Raku. These can be negated as `<!wb>` or `<!|w>`, respectively. In the last example, a left word-boundary is `<<` and a right word boundary is `>>`. Raku's match variable is `$/`, which can also be spelled `$<>`.

You can change the target class from `\w` to `<alpha>` or `<alnum>` or even to `<:Letter>` (abbreviated `<:L>`). *Nota bene:* `\w` and `<alpha>` and `<alnum>` will match underscore while `<:Letter>` and `<:L>` will not.

All the classes mentioned immediately above are Unicode-aware so any sort of "case-folding" shouldn't be a problem. You can write regexes targeting Unicode-defined `<:Ll>` lowercase letters and/or Unicode-defined `<:Lu>` uppercase letters, and you can even compare letters with the `.fc` "foldcase" routine.

Sample Input:

```
cat Example
Dog
I
Fish
su
Su adm
Amd Cat ignore
sté
a
Xa
Xá
Xå
Xà
Xä
Xb
Xß
Xœ
Xþ
```

Sample Output:

```
CAT Example
DOG
I
Fish
SU
SU ADM
AMD CAT ignore
STÉ
a
XA
XÁ
XÅ
XÀ
XÄ
XB
XSS
XŒ
XÞ
```

https://docs.raku.org/language/regexes#Anchors
https://raku.org